# All Phaser.Sprite objects I create suddenly are missing their 2D coordinates

Tags: typescript, sprite, phaser-framework

I'm making a game with Phaser in Typescript, and to make it more manageable, I created a few interfaces, and had my Sprites implement them.

Before I created the interfaces, everything worked fine. All created Sprites had 2D coordinates (`Sprite.{x,y}`) that updated correctly.

After I created the interfaces though, newly created `Sprite`s no longer contain `x` and `y` coordinates, even immediately after creation (Edge browser debugger):

[image: Tank Debug]

The "watch" list on the right shows the contents of `this`. As you can see, it has a `z`-coordinate, but no `x` or `y`-coordinates.

I didn't make any changes to the underlying physics setup, and am never explicitly deleting the properties. I wouldn't have an opportunity to though, even if I wanted to since as you can see above, they don't exist even after checking immediately after the `Sprite`'s creation. The only change I made to the base-class `Tank` was to add the `tankMover` property, but as you can see, it's not even created by the time the breakpoint is activated.

I won't/can't include all the code, since the changes I made span many files, but none of the affect the physics; they basically just add velocity to the `Sprite` in a restricted way.

To make sure it didn't have anything to do with the `Tank` class, I created a temporary `Sprite` in my `create` method of my main state. As you can see, even immediately after its creation and addition to the physics system, it doesn't have coordinates either:

[image: Temp Sprite Debug]

In Phaser, what can cause the `x` and `y` coordinate properties of a `Sprite` to fail to populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by 2 things:

- Edge not reporting the x and y coordinates of the Sprite; even though they existed.
- I accidently passed `this` instead of `this.host` to Phaser's `Phaser.Math.angleToXY` function, and for some reason Typescript's type system didn't catch it, even though it was obviously wrong.

Thanks Microsoft.